# Build PostgreSQL SELECT dynamically with different number of parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, parameters

I'd like to write my PostgreSQL (9.3) SELECT dynamically based on the user's fields filled out in the query form:

```
$cond = '';
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_a'] != '')
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod >= $2';
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_b'] != '')
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod <= $3';
$sel = ExecSQLP('SELECT field_value, field_lastmod
                FROM my_values
                WHERE field_value ILIKE \'%\' || $1 || \'%\'
                . $cond .
                ' ORDER BY node_id;'
    , array( $_REQUEST['sel_find'], $_REQUEST['sel_when_a'], $_REQUEST['sel_when_b'] ));
```

(ExecSQLP is my function to execute an SQL statement with the arguments, based on `pg_query_params`.)

This is simple and elegant, but I get an error message: `Query failed: ERROR: bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1` if sel_when_a ("after") and sel_when_b ("before") are empty.

**I think this shouldn't be an error in PostgreSQL** as it doesn't do any bad if an unused parameter is supplied. Can I suppress this error? Othervise how to build the statement with different number of parameters? I have a lot of them, not only the 3 above. It'd be terrible to prepare for the several cases with renumbered parameters if PostgreSQL doesn't allow this.

The documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-PARAMETERS-POSITIONAL is not very useful for this case.

Thanks for your tips. SQL injection vulnerability is not accepted!

(Perhaps similar to [How to handle dynamic number of parameters in querystring when building REST api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092373/how-to-handle-dynamic-number-of-parameters-in-querystring-when-building-rest-api), but the relation is not always "equals to a string".)

Answer (score 0):

I'd build the parameter array while building query. Like this:

```
$cond = '';
$params = array( $_REQUEST['sel_find'] );
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_a'] != '') {
    $params[] = $_REQUEST['sel_when_a'];
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod >= $'.count($params);
}
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_b'] != '') {
    $params[] = $_REQUEST['sel_when_b'];
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod <= $'.count($params);
}
$sel = ExecSQLP('SELECT field_value, field_lastmod
                FROM my_values
                WHERE field_value ILIKE \'%\' || $1 || \'%\''
                . $cond .
                ' ORDER BY node_id;'
    , $params ));
```

It's not very sensible to ignore wrong number or parameters - in 99% of cases it would be a programming error.

If you would've used PDO for database connection you could use named parameters like this:

```
$cond = '';
$params = array( ':sel_find' => $_REQUEST['sel_find'] );
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_a'] != '') {
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod >= :sel_when_a';
    $params[':sel_when_a'] = $_REQUEST['sel_when_a'];
}
if ($_REQUEST['sel_when_b'] != '') {
    $cond .= ' AND field_lastmod <= :sel_when_b';
    $params[':sel_when_b'] = $_REQUEST['sel_when_b'];
}
$sel = $dbh->prepare('SELECT field_value, field_lastmod
                FROM my_values
                WHERE field_value ILIKE \'%\' || :sel_find || \'%\''
                . $cond .
                ' ORDER BY node_id;')->execute($params);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bad solution. $3 will not exist if $_REQUEST['sel_when_a'] == '' but $_REQUEST['sel_when_b'] != ''

Yes then also the numbers should be generated dynamically...
I hoped there was a shorter and more elegant way.

Comment: Corrected. And proposed PDO solution with named parameters - clearer and more elegant.

Comment: Nice idea, but are you sure this is allowed in PostgreSQL?
I get `PostgreSQL error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"`.

Finally I did exactly the same solution (`$'.count($params);`) as you. Thanks.

Comment: You probably use classic `pg_connect` and other `pg_*` functions, which do not support this. To use it you have to use more modern PDO class (`$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:...')`).